# Using C# Task for event async operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, task

Suppose I have an object `SomeObj` that performs an asynchronous operation which it has implemented as an event that returns a piece of data.

I might have code that looks like this:

```cs
private void MyFunc1(Func<int> callback)
{
    SomeObj obj = SomeObj.GetSomeObj();
    obj.onAsyncComplete += callback;
}
```

So in this implementation the callback is used to asynchronously accept the resulting data (an `int`) returned by `SomeObj.onAsyncComplete`.

I'd like to move this hypothetical example to using `async` and `await`:

```cs
private async int MyFunc1()
{
    SomeObj obj = SomeObj.GetSomeObj();
    Task<int> asyncCompleteTask = /* something with obj.onAsyncComplete */
    await asyncCompleteTask;
    return asyncCompleteTask.Result;
}
```

How would I accomplish something like this? The goal is to be able to `await` the resulting `int` passed by the `onAsyncComplete` event. Assume that `SomeObj` cannot be modified.

Comment: "If you can not modify it (enough), wrap it into something you can modify" - Inofficial Motto of the MVVM Design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more visibility to BART's link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap

I would consider why you're doing this first, given that if you're implementing another library its usually best to stick with the method they intended. But if you're creating something like a wrapper for the library and really want to change the behavior.. I would create an extension or wrapper method and use a `TaskCompletionSource`:

Your `MyFunc1` could look like this:

```cs
public Task<int> MyFunc1()
{
    SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj();
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    someObj.OnAsynComplete += (r) => tcs.SetResult(r);
    someObj.GetSomeObj();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Or you could do something with an extension:

```cs
public static class SomeObjExtension
{
    public static Task<int> GetResultAsyncTask(this SomeObj someObj)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        someObj.OnAsynComplete += (r) => tcs.SetResult(r);
        someObj.GetSomeObj();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}


async void Main()
{
    SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj();
    int result = await someObj.GetResultAsyncTask();
    Console.WriteLine($"Got some number back: {result}");
}
```

If you were to run it without the extension, it follows the pattern you specified:

```cs
void Main()
{
    SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj();
    someObj.OnAsynComplete += (r) => Console.WriteLine($"Got some number back: {r}");
    someObj.GetSomeObj();
}
```

For testing, I created `SomeObj` like this:

```cs
public class SomeObj
{
    public void GetSomeObj()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            //do something...
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            OnAsynComplete?.Invoke(new Random().Next(1, 10000));
        });
    }
    public event OnAsyncCompleteHandler OnAsynComplete;
    public delegate void OnAsyncCompleteHandler(int result);
}
```

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I didn't modify SomeObj, I created the class as an example. You can see this still follows the pattern they specified, just gives me a way to test... I'm using an extension method to show how you can add the method without needing to modify the class.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This answer is correct one and does not modify `SomeObj` It's EAP to TAP conversion here you can learn more about it and conversions from other asynchronous patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` accomplished what I was looking for, cheers! For context, I was indeed creating a wrapper for a library that predated the introduction of Tasks and Async in C#, mainly for academic purposes, trying to learn how to work with Tasks better myself.

Comment: @Johannes Mark it as the answer?